# Make ql-action and ql-remove anchor tags crawable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, quill, react-quill

When running lighthouse check in chrome I am getting SEO score 90 and only ql-action and ql-remove anchor tags are not crawable.
Should i do it with the extending certain class, but I am not sure what class should i extend so if someone has some idea, it would be greatly appreciated.

I Tried to add href attribute inside custom "link handler".

```
  const qlAction: HTMLAnchorElement = tooltip.root.querySelector('.ql-action');
  const qlRemove: HTMLAnchorElement = tooltip.root.querySelector('.ql-remove');

  qlAction.setAttribute('href', '#');
  qlRemove.setAttribute('href', '#');
```

But it's still not crawable